# GAS have too many bugs with run scripts

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have many problems with run of scripts.
It sometimes skip some rows of code (that result of code unexpected) 
If it skip it, it won`t call about error in run archive

GAS do it in any of my script ever.

That example of my code:

```
function onOpen() {

  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();  // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.

   ui.createMenu('Create new list from template')

      .addItem('template 1', 'menuItem1')

      .addItem('template 2', 'menuItem2')

      .addToUi();

}

function menuItem1() {
 var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
 spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('emplate 1'), true);
 spreadsheet.duplicateActiveSheet(); // it can skip it (script will brake my template list)
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getSheets().length;
 spreadsheet.moveActiveSheet(sheet);
 spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().setName("yyyy-MM-dd "+(sheet)); // it can skip it (name won`t set)
 spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('template 1'), true);  // it can skip it (next code row will used on wrong list)
 spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().hideSheet(); // it can skip it (it won`t hided)
} 
...
```

I have an idea, that this trouble is appear of JS async working. I met that problem in another code and language with no promise system. It was a problem, that script don't wait self previous row.
Its cool that JS is async, but I dont how it work in GAS.

there is In script GAS`s IDE "asyinc ... await" schema instructed "unnecessary".
Another my try:[screen of message from GAS IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEpsa.png)

Please, help me to stabilize my scripts

Comment: `SpreadsheetApp.flush()`. But you have other errors

Comment: Thank you very match!

An another errors: is it "emplate 1"? or another?

Comment: `var sheet = ss.getSheets().length;`. `sheet` is a number not a sheet. `var numberOfSheets = ss.getSheets().length;`

Comment: O, thank you. It my naming mystake.
I'm only one who work with it, but you are right that it bednaming.

It my first question in Stackoverlow.
I didnt expect, that I will get answer so fast!
Thank you another time. )